# Pushing instantiated class in an array

Tags: php, array

I've just stumbled upon something today that seemed "unethical" in PHP. What I originally thought as malpractice, turned out to work just fine. Basically what I was wondering is if pushing an instantiated class in an array was considered proper?

Example:

```
$array = array();

array_push($array, new myClass());

foreach($array as $i => $class)
{
    $class->doSomething();  
}
```

Although this example is quite vague, the idea is there. Any input or alternatives on this matter would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example looks like a very simple "chain of command" implementation.
Looks fine to me, nothing unusual (though YYMV depending on the code-base).

You'll see things like this as an alternative to long blocks of procedural code, often when there's a bunch of distinct actions to perform that have no relation to one another. It's a nice way to clean up and cut up large classes to keep things "SRP"'d.

Comment: Great stuff. Reason for asking was due to the fact I've recently picked up PHP, migrating from Java where you'd see a lot of this stuff.